# Migrate to updated APIs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm getting an error to migrate API from GKE though I'm not using the said API `/apis/extensions/v1beta1/ingresses`

I ran the command `kubectl get deployment [mydeployment] -o yaml` and did not find the API in question

[image]

Comment: Please do share the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

It seems an IngressList is that calls the old API. To check you can use following command, this will give you the entire ingress info.

> kubectl get --raw /apis/extensions/v1beta1/ingresses | jq

I have same issue but i have upgraded node version from 1.21 to 1.22